# Decrease padding ul wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html-lists, padding

I want to decrease the padding of my ul, right now it's 40 (I think). This code works to make the padding zero:

```
ul {
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
```

}

Using this code above works but it can only be 0 when I try something like 10 or 20 it doesnt work anymore. When I inspect the element I want to change it says the padding is 40 right now.

Comment: you should accept an answer from the answes below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not shown any `HTML markup`, nor `CSS classes`/`Style sheets`. Try to resolve the conflict in the CSS itself, or append `!important` to any size value present.

```css
ul.someClass {
    padding:10px !important;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

And, it is reccommended to add a classname to the element itself, instead of assigning it to the whole `ul` element.

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than "0" add px (for example).
If you just add 10, it does not know if that is 10px, 10em, etc.

```
ul {
padding: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```